# Why is my code funtion not working as i want it to?

Tags: c, char, scanf, c-strings, conversion-specifier

Here the printAdd function is not working and I am not sure why. There is no error shown in the terminal it just doesn't print the info.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct address {
    int houseNo;
    int block;
    char city[100];
    char state;
};

void printAdd(struct address add);

int main(){
    struct address add[5];
    printf("enter info for person 1 : \n");
    scanf("%d", &add[0].houseNo);
    scanf("%d", &add[0].block);
    scanf("%s", &add[0].city);
    scanf("%s", &add[0].state);


    printAdd(add[0]);

    
    return 0;
}

void printAdd(struct address add){
    printf("address is : %d, %d, %s, %s\n", add.houseNo, add.block, add.city, add.state);
}
```

Comment: It is printing it. Your app is exiting before it can be seen. Add code to wait for a keypress before you return.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  always enable the warnings options when compiling  for `gcc` suggest using the options:   `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic  -std=gnu11`

Answer (score 1):

These calls of `scanf`

```
scanf("%s", &add[0].city);
scanf("%s", &add[0].state);
```

are incorrect.

You should write

```
scanf("%99s", add[0].city);
scanf(" %c", &add[0].state);
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string in the last call of scanf. It allows to skip white space characters.

Also in the call of `printf` you have to write

```
printf("address is : %d, %d, %s, %c\n", add.houseNo, add.block, add.city, add.state);
```

That is the last conversion specifier shall be `%c` instead of `%s`.

And it will be better to declare the function like

```
void printAdd( const struct address *add);
```

That is instead of passing the whole structure it will be better to pass a pointer to the object of the structure type.

```
void printAdd( const struct address *add){
    printf("address is : %d, %d, %s, %c\n", add->houseNo, add->block, add->city, add->state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very likely this is the problem:

```
scanf("%s", &add[0].state);
```

Here you ask `scanf` to read a *string* into the single-character `state` member. Either read a *character* with `%c` or make `state` an array that can hold at least two characters (for a single-character "state" designation).